# Adding inline blocks(math equation) in slate js

Tags: mathjax, mathml, slatejs

I am using slate js rich text editor, everything is working as expected. I am using separate editor for inserting math equation, how it works is

1. User writes text in slate editor
2. Then to insert equation user writes eqation in maths editor and click on insert equation
3. On click of this button i add new block like

   `change.insertInline({
       type: 'equation',
       data: { math: editor.getMathML() }
     })`

and handling render of the block by renderNode function

and one more block to continue writing in editor like `change.insertBlock('paragraph')`

Functionality wise everything is working as expected, but since i am adding equation as a block slate is rendering it in new line.

My questions are

1. How can i render customBlock in same line
2. Is there any other way of continue editing in same editor apart from `change.insertBlock('paragraph')`

Comment: Inserting a block will split paragraph into 3 paragraphs. The trick that worked for me was to set data to 'inline: true' on the current paragraph right before the insertion and render paragraphs as `{display: 'inline-flex', marginBottom: '1rem'}` when given that modified data.

Comment: Hi Mawa! I am trying to insert the equations inside SlateJS. I have come across some packages like Math type. But they do not give much control over editing the equation.
May I know the approach you have gone with in slatejs to insert equations!
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to "display: inline".  The element can be a block but still render inline.